# Using posgresql to_tsquery prefix match on column with possible multiple values

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, matching

This works fine if only querying one word:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'matchsticks only applicable things'), to_tsquery('english', 'match:*'),
to_tsvector('english', 'matchsticks only applicable things') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'match:*')
```

Now how can i make it work with column like db_column which can have string with spaces:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'matchsticks only applicable things'), to_tsquery('english', db_column),
to_tsvector('english', 'matchsticks only applicable things') @@ to_tsquery('english', db_column)
```

Example if `db_column = "match test square"` and i want to pass `"match:*&test:*&square:*"` ? tried plainto_tsquery, but is missing the ':*' to allow prefix matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the tsquery string:

```sql
select  (replace(
          plainto_tsquery('english', 'match test square')::text,
          ' &',
          ':*&') || ':*'
         )::tsquery;


             tsquery
----------------------------------
 'match':* & 'test':* & 'squar':*
(1 row)
```